# weak cannot be applied to non-class type uiimageview

Tags: swift, weak-references

I have a class in swift that needs to have a weak pointer to an array of objects that is allocated in another class. I have

```
class myView: UIView
{
    var lines:[CAShapeLayer] = []
    weak var avatars : [UIImageView]?
```

The error I get is

> 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type '[UIImageView]'

I also tried to no avail:

```
weak var avatars : [UIImageView?]?
```

Answer (score 29):

**Weak Cannot be applied to non-class type:**

It means you can’t have a weak reference to any value type instance(e.g. Array, Dictionary, String, etc…) because these all are struct not class. You only give weak reference which are of class-type(e.g UIImage, UIImageView, etc…).In this case, you are trying to give weak reference to UIImageView Array and we know array is a value type, so it is not possible.

For example:

```
weak var str: String? //CompileTime Error(Wrong)

weak var arr: Array? //CompileTime Error(Wrong)

weak var imageView: UIImageView? //Correct
```

In case of Protocol:
If we have just a protocol of struct type:

```
protocol SomeProtocol{
    func doSomething()  
}
```

We cannot declare variables of this type as weak:

```
weak var delegate: SomeProtocol? //CompileTime Error(Wrong)
```

But if we make protocol of class type like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class{
    func doSomething()
}
```

We can declare variables of this type as weak:

```
weak var delegate: SomeProtocol? //Correct
```

I think you easily understand it, why this happens in protocol?

Same reason: You only give weak reference which are of class-type

Comment: you're a saviour. Thanks

Comment: what if we use a non-class bound protocol as a property of a ViewController? I mean we can't make it weak, so will it create retain cycle??

Answer (score 10):

> needs to have a weak pointer to an array of objects

Well, as the error message tells you, you can't. Array is a struct, not a class. You can't have a weak reference to a struct instance; it's a value type, so it doesn't do `weak` memory management.

Nor does it need it - there is no danger of a retain cycle, because this is a value type. You should ask yourself why you think it does need it. Perhaps you think `weak` and Optional always go together, but they do not. You've already declared this an Optional array; that is enough, surely.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to apply `weak` to an `Array` of type `UIImageView`. `Array` is a struct.